# Child div same size as Parent Overflows

Tags: html, css

After doing many Google searches, I can't find why children of a parent with the same size are overflowing.

For example

```html
<div style="background:blue;width:500px;height:40px">
      <div style="border:1px solid red;height:40px;font-size:0px;display:inline-block;width:30%;">
      </div>
      <div style="border:1px solid black;height:40px;font-size:0px;display:inline-block;width:70%;">
      </div>
    </div>
```

The code above shows the first children div tag has a height of 1px more than parent. Also when both children percent width add up to 100%, the parent still cannot fit the two divs.

Comment: it's because of `border`, set [**`box-sizing:border-box`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: Don't forget about borders. Moreover, the childrens is `inline-block`s, so the space (or tabulation) between childrens has own width. Set `box-sizing: border-box' and remove any spaces between blocks.

Comment: @Alexander How do I remove the space between the blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget about borders. Moreover, the childrens is `inline-block`s, so the space (or tabulation) between childrens has own width. Set `box-sizing: border-box` and remove any spaces between blocks:

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:yellow;width:500px;height:40px">
  <div style="border:1px solid red;height:40px;font-size:0px;display:inline-block;width:30%;">
  </div><div style="border:1px solid blue;height:40px;font-size:0px;display:inline-block;width:70%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Firstly - box model

Your border is adding size to the box, most people use [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) as a default these days

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

(if you've the option, just throw it in your global CSS and be done with it)

Highly recommend reading up on the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model), a basic understanding of that will save you  much pain (or at least help you search for answers!)

With your example:

```html
<div style="background:blue;width:500px;height:40px">
      <div style="box-sizing:border-box; border:1px solid red;height:40px;font-size:0px;display:inline-block;width:30%;">
      </div>
      <div style="box-sizing:border-box; border:1px solid black;height:40px;font-size:0px;display:inline-block;width:70%">
      </div>
    </div>
```

## Secondly - `inline-block` elements

You're facing a [common](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) [issue](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block) [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678929/display-inline-block-what-is-that-space) [inline](https://university.webflow.com/article/troubleshooting-spacing-issues-caused-by-inline-block) [block](https://medium.com/@drewisthe/an-inline-block-intervention-6ce18a3f7edf) elements where whitespace *between tags* is affecting your rendered content.

Generally best just to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) or if you're restricted to old browsers, `float`s

### Using flexbox

```html
<div style="background:blue;width:500px;height:40px;display: flex;">
  <div style="box-sizing:border-box; border:1px solid red;height:40px;font-size:0px;width:30%;">
  </div>
  <div style="box-sizing:border-box; border:1px solid black;height:40px;font-size:0px;width:70%">
  </div>
</div>
```

### Using float left

```html
<div style="background:blue;width:500px;height:40px;/* display: flex; */">
  <div style="box-sizing:border-box;border:1px solid red;height:40px;font-size:0px;width:30%;float: left;">
  </div>
  <div style="box-sizing:border-box;border:1px solid black;height:40px;font-size:0px;width:70%;float: left;">
  </div>
</div>
```

### If you really have to use inline-block

See my links above for workarounds, all of which are unsatisfactory in some way, eg.

```html
<div style="background:blue;width:500px;height:40px">
  <div style="box-sizing:border-box; border:1px solid red;height:40px;font-size:0px;display:inline-block;width:30%;">
  </div><!-- commenting out carriage return
  --><div style="box-sizing:border-box; border:1px solid black;height:40px;font-size:0px;display:inline-block;width:70%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! I will definitely read about the box model. However, the two children divs still doesn't fit side by side in the parent

Comment: apologies - seems I only answered half of the question, will revise

Comment: Good solution +1

Answer (score 0):

Its because of `box-sizing` css property...its default and initial value is `content-box` which means the element width and height include the content, not its padding, border

You will need to set `box-sizing: border-box` to the div so that the padding and border will be included in the width and height of element.

And your divs are not side by side because of the `display:inline-block`. Thats how its works. Setting elements in one line using `inline-block` create spaces between them like the words when we type, its a common thing.

So to remove the space between them either you remove space in your code between these two divs or set `font-size:0` to the parent div and then set `font-size: initial` to the child elements.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:blue;width:500px;height:40px;font-size:0;">
  <div style="border:1px solid red;height:40px;font-size:0px;display:inline-block;width:30%;">
  </div>
  <div style="border:1px solid pink;height:40px;font-size:0px;display:inline-block;width:70%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or another option is use `Flexbox` if browser support is not an issue

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:blue;width:500px;height:40px;display:flex;">
  <div style="border:1px solid red;height:40px;font-size:0px;display:inline-block;width:30%;">
  </div>
  <div style="border:1px solid pink;height:40px;font-size:0px;display:inline-block;width:70%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but how do I fit both children in the parent?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```html
<div style="background:blue;width:500px;height:41px">
  <div style="border: 1px solid red;height:40px;width:29%;float:left;">
  </div>
  <div style="border:1px solid black;height:40px;width:70%; float:left">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't fit the two children inside the parent

Comment: hi bro, check running example again. i have updated the code. i hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you need to add `box-sizing: border-box` to the body and `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent, also change `display: inline-block` of children

ie:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child first"> </div>
    <div class="child second"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.parent {
  background:blue;
  width:500px;
  height:40px; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.first {
  width:30%;
  border:4px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
}
.second {
  width: 70%;
  border:4px solid pink;
  display: inline-block;
}
.child {
 height:40px;
 font-size:0px;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

Check this
https://jsfiddle.net/_ahmed_ab/4301hwmc/1/