# img height 100 percent scrollbar

Tags: css

An `img` with `height: 100%` applies a scroll bar to the web browser.

If there is no `<!DOCTYPE>` tag, there is no scroll bar.
When you insert the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag, a scroll bar is created.

I tried several things, but I think `<!DOCTYPE>` is a problem

I would like to make the scroll bar disappear without using `overflow`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            img {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="test.jpg">
    </body>
</html>
```

The above source code has no scroll bars, but inserting `<!doctype html>` creates a scroll bar.

I have used the developer tools to make sure the `html`, `body`, and `img` heights are the same.

I want to know why `<!doctype html>` causes scroll bars.
And I want to know how to fix it without using `overflow` in CSS.

I have tried several codes:
[image: I have tried several source code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: block` to `<img>`.

By default, `<img>` has `display: inline` as default display style. And `inline` and `inline-block` display style will apply a blank space between elements.

To remove the blank space, you can read these links:

1. [Display: Inline block - What is that space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678929/display-inline-block-what-is-that-space)
2. https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Alternatively, just make its display style to `display: block`.

**Before**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/Sig07-006.jpg">
```

**After:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  /* ADD THIS */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/Sig07-006.jpg">
```

As to why declaring `<!DOCTYPE html>` affects the layout, you can read [this MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Doctype).

Basically, without `<!DOCTYPE html`>, the browser will render the page with older render mode to support old web pages.

Comment: thank you. And why doctype is affected?

Comment: @mp662002 see updated answer